# Get character followed by new line item using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, character

I am trying to get the character on a new line after a specific letter using regex. My raw data looks like the below:

```
 Total current charges (please see Current account details) $38,414.69
 ID Number
 1001166UNBEB
 ACCOUNT SUMMARY
 SVL0
 BALANCE OVERDUE - PLEASE PAY IMMEDIATELY $42,814.80
```

I want to get the `ID Number`

My attempt is here:

```
ID_num = re.compile(r'[^ID Number[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)]{12}')
```

The length of ID num is always 12, and always after `ID Number` which is why I am specifying the length in my expression and trying to detect the elements after that.

But this is not working as desired.

Would anyone help me, please?

Comment: Are the quote characters in the raw data?

Comment: Maybe you can use `m = re.search(r"ID Number',\s*'(\w+)'", text)` and then `print(m.group(1))`. See https://regex101.com/r/MXnf00/1

Comment: You clearly know that square brackets are for characters sets because you wrote `[\r\n]` to match either of those characters. So why do you have `[` before `^ID Number`?

Comment: The regexp doesn't match the quotes and comma after `ID Number`

Comment: If this is part of the output of `print(somelist)`, you could use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse it into a list, then search the list instead of using a clumsy regexp.

Comment: @Barmar No, it is from a PDF file and I am splitting the strings using a new line, and it is an output from python. The quote character is not part of the raw data.

Comment: Then use `(?m)^ID Number\s*(\w+)` - https://regex101.com/r/MXnf00/2, but make sure you apply it to a *string*. Not a list of strings. And if it is a list of strings, use https://ideone.com/RTNAgr

Comment: So this is a list of strings, not a single string?

Comment: Not a list of strings, characters from pdf, and used 'line.split('\n')' to be able to loop through each line of characters.

Comment: Right, do not do that if you want to use `m = re.search(r"^ID Number\s*(\w+)", text, re.M)`. Or, if you split, you will be able to use https://ideone.com/RTNAgr

Comment: If the id is alway 12 characters `^\s([A-Z0-9]{12})`

Comment: @Cooper This is working but also getting another string, so I have to tell regex that I only need the one that is below ID Number.

Comment: I work in Javascript so I use String.match() method.  With that method using /gm it returns all of the results and in this case I would use `String.match(/^\s([A-Z0-9]{12})/gm)[0];` So if you know it's always going to be the first one then that might work.  Other wise you might need to know more about the two strings and take advantage of their differences or similarities.  BTW both Barmar and Wiktor know a lot more about this than I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is not working because of the use of `[ ]` at the beginning of the pattern, these are used for character sets.
So replace it with `( )`.
Your pattern would look like: `r'^ID Number[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+){12}'`

But you can simplify your pattern to: `ID Number[\s]+(\w+)`
`\r\n` will be matched in `\s` and numbers and alpha chars in `\w`.

```py
import re
s = """
Total current charges (please see Current account details) $38,414.69
ID Number
1001166UNBEB
ACCOUNT SUMMARY
SVL0
BALANCE OVERDUE - PLEASE PAY IMMEDIATELY $42,814.80
"""
print(re.findall(r"ID Number[\s]+(\w+)", s))
# ['1001166UNBEB']
```